# Define a function as a default in a field in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to do something like this:

```
var categorySchema = new Schema({
  id: {
    unique: true,
    default: function() {
      //set the last item inserted id + 1 as the current value.
    }
  },
  name: String
});
```

This is posible?.

Comment: How would you use it?

Comment: for example i can set the id value using another value as a reference without intervention, everytime a new value is added.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var categorySchema = new Schema({
  id     : {
    type : Number
  },
  name   : {
    type : String
  }
});

// Define a pre-save method for categorySchema
categorySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var self = this;

  // Example of your function where you get the last ID
  getLastId(function(id){
    // Assigning the id property and calling next() to continue
    self.id = id;
    next();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, sure, answer commented :)

Comment: Can this not be done in line like the question suggests?